# Changing the separator character in a masked textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm attempting to use a masked textbox to input an IP and the digits are currently being separated by a comma. Is there any way to replace the comma character with the dot character?

This is the definition of my masked textbox so far:

```
// 
// txtIPAddressForSaving
// 
this.txtIPAddressForSaving.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 30F);
this.txtIPAddressForSaving.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(148, 115);
this.txtIPAddressForSaving.Mask = "009.009.009.009";
this.txtIPAddressForSaving.Name = "txtIPAddressForSaving";
this.txtIPAddressForSaving.PromptChar = '.';
this.txtIPAddressForSaving.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(463, 53);
this.txtIPAddressForSaving.TabIndex = 13;
this.txtIPAddressForSaving.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: And that configuration uses a `,` for the separator?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud That is correct, as stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure I read that right. The configuration seems correct to me.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I suspect that the regional settings might be interfering though..

Comment: `PromptChar` seems about ok, could be a localization / regional thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.txtIPAddressForSaving.Mask = @"009\.009\.009\.009";
```

Another option is to use `InvariantCulture` for your `MaskedTextBox` (keep the old format):

```
txtIPAddressForSaving.Mask = "009.009.009.009";
txtIPAddressForSaving.Culture = System.Globalization
                                      .CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Note that, the culture we change is applied only for the `MaskedTextBox` and doesn't apply any other controls.

Comment: Done! Sorry, but I haven't been on so during the weekend :)

Answer (score 2):

Set the current `Thread`s culture accordingly.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

*Note, this may affect behavior in other areas of your application that may rely on a particular culture.*